# Invalid Generic Type with NEST

Tags: c#, nest

I have this method i want to make Generic type. This would allow the method to accept any class Model I pass in for exaple Blog model, Post Model, Author Model etc.

So that, anytime I call this method, i would just pass in the Model and query.

```
public T SearchIndex(T model, string query)
{
    var srchService = client.Search<model>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m.Query("hello"))
    ));

    return T;
}
```

I am using NEST from elasticsearch. I want to avoid repeating code for All the models. from the above, T => T is a type which is not valid in this context.

Comment: You need to use `client.Search<T>` and if you get compilation errors, fix them so it satisfies the constraints placed on `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty wrong. You are mixing types and variables.
Specifically, `T` is a type and you can't return types. And `model` is a variable and you can't use variables as generic type parameters.

Maybe you want this?

```
public T SearchIndex<T>(string query)
{
    return client.Search<T>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m.Query("hello"))
    ));
}
```

Comment: There are other compilation errors though. I am working on them.